# Clojure map runs in cider, but not lein run

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm having an issue where my project runs in Cider, but not with `lein run`.

Consider these functions in core.clj:

```
(def my-vec ["a" "b" "c"])

(defn dostuff [x] (spit "/home/dirty/file.txt" x :append true))

(defn -main [& args] (map dostuff my-vec))
```

Now, when I open Cider repl and enter `(-main)`, this will run and `file.txt` will contain "abc...". However, if I go to the project with the terminal and run `lein run` it runs for a few moments and then shuts down. But `file.txt` is not written to. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Not sure that this can be answered without more context -- a `project.clj`, and the `ns` declaration from your `core.clj` at the minimum.

Comment: I'm afraid the actual project.clj, ns, and core.clj are impractical to share. So if you cannot help without them, thank you anyway.

Comment: Heh. Actually, looks like @diego nailed it. That said, for the future, StackOverflow's policies are such that questions with a SSCCE ("short, self-contained, correct example") are strongly preferred, though indeed, it's appropriate to remove things that aren't required to reproduce to achieve "short". Something not complete enough be run isn't self-contained or correct. See http://sscce.org/ (as linked by the related SO close reason) for a longer discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I still usually get what I want in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` is a lazy sequence, it's not meant for side effects. If you want to force the realization of the lazy sequence, you need to wrap your `map` in a `doall`. You shouldn't be using map for this in the first place as you don't care about the resulting sequence. See `doseq`:

```
(doseq [x my-vec] (dostuff x))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Diego said, what you really want is doseq, especially since spit just returns nil and so map cannot give you a meaningful result.  You can overcome the laziness of plain "map" by using "mapv", which is **not** lazy and returns a vector result.  Try this:

```
(defn -main [& args] (mapv dostuff my-vec))
user=> (-main)
[nil nil nil]
```

If you change dostuff to return a value, then mapv makes sense:

```
user=> (defn dostuff [x] (spit "file.txt" x :append true) x )
#'user/dostuff
user=> (-main)
["a" "b" "c"]
```